# construct a conditional with "where"

Tags: word-usage

I guess I am aware of the concept of [***conditionals***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals).

> Conditional sentences consider imagined or uncertain situations and the possible results of these situations.

`If` is the most commonly used word to construct a conditional.

`If + subject + present simple, subject + modal(future) + Verb(base)`

> If a lawyer reads the document, we will see if we’ve missed anything important.

sometime, `when` could also do the job.

> if ice melts
>   it becomes water
>
> when ice melts
>   it becomes water

A few minutes ago, I saw an use with "where"

> **Where** there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb

Given it comes from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position), I believe it is almost certainly idiomatic.

The question is when would people use "where" to construct a conditional? In other words, in what kind of situations, people would use "where" to construct a conditional? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where I go, you will go. That could be seen as a conditional. But what's your point? Where I went, you would go if you could.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` is used here with the meaning of `In situations that...`.

Similarly `when` could be used, but emphasizing the situation's time occurrence instead of its location occurrence (as does `where`).

---

### Here comes some examples:

`Where two eat, three eat` (*popular saying*)

`When we get home, the dog always barks laudy`

`Where there's smoke, there's fire` (*popular saying*)

`When she looks at me, I get embarrassed`

---

> Observe there is more conditional sentence cases than just the **imagined situations** you defined in the beginning of your sentence. For this `where` and `when` examples, the [in case of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-case-of) or [as long as](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-long-as-and-so-long-as) cases fit better

Comment: Thank you. I am still confused about that. I guess other sign words (would I call them this?), e.g. "if", "when", "as long as", "in case of" could also express  the meaning of `In situations that...`, so the meaning is not a characteristic to distinguish them, right?

Comment: I guess there are two possibilities when talking about the usage of a group of words. Possibility#1: the words in that group are interchangeable; Possibility#2: they are not. When talking about Possibility#2, there would be some characteristics to distinguish what situation is suitable to which word. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Anyway, your examples give me lots of helpful information. Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Comment: [There are more cases. and Here come some examples] I cannot understand your last paragraph at all.