# "**When**" she looks at me, I get embarrassed

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([construct a conditional with "where"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241422/109190)), a nice answerer gives this example to demonstrate when to use "when" to construct a conditional.

> When she looks at me, I get embarrassed

First of all, is it a conditional? The sentence does not seem to fit any of the three patterns in the [Cambridge Dictionary tutorial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if).

Secondly, I suppose that is a conditional and some kind of conditional where "when" is the best choice.

Consider other two possibilities

> ex#2 If she looks at me, I get embarrassed
>
> ex#3 Where she looks at me, I get embarrassed

ex#2 sounds unusual, #3 does even more.

That answerer describes this kind of situations this way

> "when" could be used, but emphasizing the situation's time occurrence

I guess this is a reasonable explanation. Could someone please gives some other explanations easier to understand? Thanks in advance.

---

**Note:** There are 2 questions in here. Please don't ignore the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, it may help you to consider the concept of logic in mathematics.  A hypothesis is followed by a conclusion (i.e., if, then).  Applying this to your example shows that if a thing happens, then this is the result.

> When she looks at me, I get embarrassed

This sentence is a conditional because the if/then construction depends on something being a condition of the initiating action.

As to the use of "when" in a conditional, this is an additional constraint to denote that the result happens relevant to this time occasion.  "If" might also say the same thing, but "when" implies a potentially ongoing occurrence of what happens in this conditional situation.

Comment: "When" in this case is best translated as "At the moment in time when"